# How to add right border of grid in Chart contol

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

[image]

Here is my code for setting properties of chart which is attached above:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "t";
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "w(t)";
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = classes[0].First();
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = classes[m - 1].Last();
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = delta_t;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.####}";
```

I need to add right border of grid so that it will be as it is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right border is missing since your data don't nicely fit into the area.

There are many ways to fix this.

Here is the simplest one:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

This adds a secondary Y-Axis and turns off its labels.

You can style it as needed:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LineWidth = 3;
```

[image]

You could also draw a line or add an annotation but this is by far the easiest solution.

Comment: Could you kindly help me with such a question: how to add label with maximum value of X-axis?

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds a lot simpler than it is. The standard labels follow their own rules and adding a custom label will turn the standard labels all off. Maybe you can play with AxisX.Maximum to include the last datapoint? (This would create 10 labels: `chart2.Refresh(); ax.Interval = (ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum)  / 9f;` Or you could drawString the text in the PostPaint event. Or use CustomLabels all the way.